# Javascript: Get all elements with id id[x]

Tags: javascript

Using javascript how do I get the number of elements present with the id of id[x]?

**Sample HTML:**

```
<input name="vrow[0]" id="vrow[0]" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[1]" id="vrow[1]" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[2]" id="vrow[2]" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[3]" id="vrow[3]" value="0" type="text"/>
```

The above html is generated depending on user input. How do I detect how many elements are present using javascript?

Currently I can detect presence of an element like this

**Sample Javascript**

```
if(document.getElementById('vrow[0]')){
var row=0;
    }
if(document.getElementById('vrow[1]')){
row=1;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[]` [are not valid characters in ID attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name) in HTML4.01. Even in HTML5, however, you should use the name attribute (without the numeric indexes), and then use [*getElementsByName()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName):

```
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
```

```
var vrows = document.getElementsByName("vrow");
alert(vrows.length);
```

Note that older versions of IE and Opera may return elements with `id` attributes that have the same value as the name specified in *getElementsByName()*.  IE may also return non-input elements with a name attribute that has the same value.

Comment: FWIW, getElementsByName() isn't supported in IE or Opera. Or rather, it's supported, but not correctly: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: @Robusto: Provided you look out for those issues, there shouldn't be any problems.  Updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

```
var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<inputTags.length;i++)
if(inputTags[i].id.contains('vrow[')
count++;
```

Comment: interesting. but i get a Object does not support this property or method.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you want to stick with the names of your input elements you can use:

```
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));
var rows = inputs.filter(function (el) { return el.name.indexOf('vrow[') == 0 });
alert(rows.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

getElementById always returns one element (since id are unique). getElementsByName can result a list of elements.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function getElements() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByName("vrow[]");
   alert(elements.length);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="getElements()">
<input name="vrow[]" id="vrow_0" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[]" id="vrow_1" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[]" id="vrow_2" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow[]" id="vrow_3" value="0" type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a JavaScript library with a query function supporting CSS3, such as Prototype, you can use the attribute starts-with selector to find id attributes beginning with vrow[

So in Prototype this would be

`$$('input[id^=vrow[]').each`

NB this is untested, you might have to escape the [ in the selector

[Prototype $$ function](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/dollardollar/)