# Check empty field from html array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation

I have a simple HTML files with book seats field as array , the code below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?> /><?php echo $i; ?>

<input type="submit" value="BOOK" onclick = "checkIfSeatEmpty()" />
```

The javascript I used to validate if the field `book` is empty is:

```
var x=document.forms["bkfrm"].getElementById("chkbx").value;

 //alert(x);   alerts 'undefined' !
// var x=document.forms["bkfrm"].getElementById("book").length;
    alert(x);
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
return TRUE;
```

But the above code alerts as `undefined` ! How can I check if the field is empty?

Comment: There is no such id 'chkbx' in your code.

Comment: Just add id="book". In your code there is only name property but no id property. getElementById search elements by id.

Comment: You can cehck this one [Javascript: Get all elements with id id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717542/javascript-get-all-elements-with-id-idx)

Comment: There should be no need to navigate to `document.forms["bkfrm"]` before calling `getElementById`.  Element ids should be unique thus `document.getElementById('chkbx')` should be sufficient. If you have multiple elements with the same id in a single page you are generating invalid code. Also, using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.forms["bkfrm"].getElementById` will be faster too.

Answer (score 0):

try like following

```
var x=document.forms["bkfrm"].getElementById("book").checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no such id as chkbx or book in your html code.. use the following code

Jquery

$("input[name='book']:checked").val();